# Resize RichTextBox according to number of lines and font size

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I have a RichTextBox on VB.NET Winforms, and I want it to display (say) 12 lines of text in Liberation Mono 10pt font. I can resize it manually of course, but I want to programmatically resize it according to the font size and number of lines. The thing I'm struggling with is how to work out the height of a single line. I tried:

```
RichTextBox.Height = RichTextBox.Font.Height
```

and:

```
RichTextBox.Height = RichTextBox.Font.GetHeight
```

But neither seemed to give me the exact dimensions I wanted. Is there a way to measure the exact height of a line in a RTB?

Thanks @Arman, I did this in the end:

```
Public Function GetHeightOfFirstNumLines(ByVal RTB As RichTextBox, ByVal NumLines As Integer) As Integer
    Dim Position1 = RTB.GetPositionFromCharIndex(RTB.GetFirstCharIndexFromLine(0))
    Dim Position2 = RTB.GetPositionFromCharIndex(RTB.GetFirstCharIndexFromLine(NumLines))
    Return Position2.Y - Position1.Y
End Function
```

Then in the Form.Load event, this code:

```
Dim RTBSize As New Size(TextRenderer.MeasureText("M", MemoryRtb.Font, MemoryRtb.Size, TextFormatFlags.WordBreak))
    MemoryRtb.ClientSize = New Size(MemoryRtb.ClientSize.Width, (RTBSize.Height * 11) + 5)
```

Comment: You are ignoring the borders.  Assign ClientSize instead.

Comment: Does ClientSize ignore the borders too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lines can have different height, so you can do something like this:

```
Private Shared Function GetHeightOfFirstLines(ByVal Rtb As RichTextBox, ByVal NumLines As Integer) As Integer
    Dim p1 = Rtb.GetPositionFromCharIndex(Rtb.GetFirstCharIndexFromLine(0))
    Dim p2 = Rtb.GetPositionFromCharIndex(Rtb.GetFirstCharIndexFromLine(NumLines))

    Return p2.Y - p1.Y
End Function
```

Then

```
RichTextBox1.ClientSize = New Size(RichTextBox1.ClientSize.Width, GetHeightOfFirstLines(RichTextBox1, 10))
```

This however requires that you already have 10 lines of text in the textbox. If you don't, you can get the height of the first line and assume the future ten lines will be of same height:

```
RichTextBox1.ClientSize = New Size(RichTextBox1.ClientSize.Width, GetHeightOfFirstLines(RichTextBox1, 1) * 10)
```

Comment: I'm a little confused - why does your solution require at least 10 lines of text? I'm using a monospace font and the size will stay the same, so I should only need the height of one line, right?

Comment: @LeoKing Yes, if you know for sure all lines will have same height, just use the last example.

Comment: `RTB.GetFirstCharIndexFromLine(NumLines)` where `NumLines = 1` returns -1 - the textbox is empty, so I suppose it's trying to access a line that doesn't exist. Can you see a way around this?

Answer (score 2):

Use `TextRenderer.MeasureText()`

```
Dim rtbSize As New Size(TextRenderer.MeasureText(RichTextBox1.Text, RichTextBox1.Font, RichTextBox1.Size, TextFormatFlags.WordBreak))

RichTextBox1.Height = rtbSize.Height + 10
```

Comment: Rich text box can have different font for each individual character, and different interline interval for each paragraph. Measuring all the text using single font and single `WordBreak` flag makes no sense in this context. Even if a rich text box only uses a single font and same interline interval for all paragraphs, `MeasureText` will ignore all formatting that exists in the RTB except for the font size. The difference can be huge.

Comment: According to MSDN, `TextRenderer.MeasureText` _Provides the size, in pixels, of the specified text when drawn with the **specified font and formatting instructions**, using the specified size to create the initial bounding rectangle for the text._

Comment: By *formatting instructions* they mean the [flags](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textformatflags.aspx) passed as the last parameter. Rich text box contains [RTF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rich_Text_Format). `MeasureText` does not understand RTF. If it did, you could make your code work by replacing `RichTextBox1.Text` with `RichTextBox1.Rtf`.

Comment: My RTB is empty by default, if I supplied the Text then it would return 0, surely. Would this work if I supplied the tallest possible character?

Comment: Yes, this will adapt according to the font, and the size of that font as I already did/tested. I thought your RTB have texts in default. In that case, call the above code whenever you want through an event.

Comment: The `+10` is for the adjustment I made in accordance to the border of RTB. It works just fine but if you don't want to this adjustment, use `ClientSize` instead.

Comment: I used ClientSize, but it wasn't quite adjusted. I changed it to +5 and now it looks fine. I couldn't get @GSerg's solution to work, so accepted :).

Comment: @LeoKing ClientSize should ignore the border.

Comment: No, this solution *does* work, with adjustments to the numbers.

Comment: @LeoKing Yeah but why did you choose the other one?

Comment: @LeoKing Yes you did. You accepted my answer which you're saying doesn't work for you. You probably meant to accept this answer instead. Please do, by clicking the tick under the voting arrows.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, @GSerg's was indeed the answer I meant to accept - I used parts of both answers.